# Heroku Page doesn't exist for custom put action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, routes

I am following along with Railscast 035 Custom REST Actions. I have everything working locally, but when I pushed to heroku, I am getting a page does not exist error for `/tasks/2/complete` [Heroku App](http://custom-rest-actions.herokuapp.com/tasks) [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/the4dpatrick/035-custom-rest-actions)

When I click on `complete task` link, I should create a `put` request to the rails app's `tasks#complete` action. Instead I am getting a 404 error. In my logs I have the following

```
method=GET path=/task/2/complete host=custom-rest-actions.herokuapp.com
request_id=16761046-c4fc-4164-b0bb-f6ed6191d71a fwd="98.207.180.92" dyno=web.1 
connect=7ms service=19ms status=404 bytes=1829
```

`heroku run rake routes`

```
         Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                   Controller#Action
           root GET    /                             tasks#index
completed_tasks GET    /tasks/completed(.:format)    tasks#completed
  complete_task PUT    /tasks/:id/complete(.:format) tasks#complete
          tasks GET    /tasks(.:format)              tasks#index
                POST   /tasks(.:format)              tasks#create
       new_task GET    /tasks/new(.:format)          tasks#new
      edit_task GET    /tasks/:id/edit(.:format)     tasks#edit
           task GET    /tasks/:id(.:format)          tasks#show
                PATCH  /tasks/:id(.:format)          tasks#update
                PUT    /tasks/:id(.:format)          tasks#update
                DELETE /tasks/:id(.:format)          tasks#destroy
```

Index.html.erb

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= link_to task.name, task %></td>
        <td>| <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_task_path(task) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Complete task', complete_task_path(task), method: :put %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller

```
def completed
  @tasks = Task.where(completed: true)
end

def complete
  @task.update_attribute :completed, true
  flash[:notice] = 'Task Completed'
  redirect_to completed_tasks_path
end
```

routes

```
resources :tasks do
  get 'completed', on: :collection
  put 'complete', on: :member
end
```

I don't think you need a view for that action because it redirects to the `completed_tasks_path`

Answer (score 0):

Try changing from `put` to `patch` and seeing if that fixes it?

I tried the app, recreated the error, but can't see any problems with your code. Maybe you could also try this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :tasks do
    member do
        patch :complete
    end
end
```